no matching index template found for data stream [restored_kibana-event-log-ds]

[ElasticHost] policy [kibana-event-log-policy] for index [restored_kibana-event-log-7.1
7.9-000002] on an error step due to a transient error, moving back to the failed step [check-rollover-ready] for execution. retry attempt [4439]
[2024-07-18T00:17:26,385][ERROR][o.e.x.i.IndexLifecycleRunner] [ElasticHost] policy [kibana-event-log-policy] for index [restored_kibana-event-log-7.1
7.9-000002] failed on step [{"phase":"hot","action":"rollover","name":"check-rollover-ready"}]. Moving to ERROR step
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [.kibana-event-log-7.17.9] does not point to index [restored_kibana-event-log-7.17.9-0
00002]

Above issue i am facing in 8.11 and 8.13 version of Elasticsearch and kibana
Please help me to solve this issue. This index is system index because i didnot created this index. why this index is created and how to handle this index to solve the issue.
What is use of this index restored_kibana-event-log-7.17.9-000002
when this index is created and how to solve this index issue.
I dindot created this index, i think this is system index.

What's inside the alias?  GET _alias/.kibana-event-log-7.17.9

{"error":"alias [.kibana-event-log-7.17.9] missing","status":404}

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
